# Creating Invoices Line Items via REST

Tags: php, rest, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I can sucessfully create an Invoice - but it seems I can't create the LineItems for it.
From where would I take the products, listed on the line items?

At the moment I'm doing:

```
$aProductResult = $SuiteCRM->setRelationship('AOS_Invoices', $aInvoiceResult['id'], 'aos_invoices_aos_product_quotes', '11173ff5-67a3-210d-030f-58fff7b9c3e0');
```

which returns

> Array ( [created] => 0 [failed] => 1 [deleted] => 0 )[/quote]

I changed the IDs to products_quote, to products but it never creates the relationship.

When I `print_r` the data, it seems to be fine as well:

```
Array
(
  [session] => ku72sbgi87886onav0vsto8n73
  [module_name] => AOS_Invoices
  [module_id] => d615a339-44f4-79f7-6db0-5902f5d96fd9
  [link_field_name] => aos_invoices_aos_product_quotes
  [related_ids] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11173ff5-67a3-210d-030f-58fff7b9c3e0
    )

)
```

I guess it's just about which to relate and which IDs to use?
I'm using https://github.com/daniel-samson/suitecrm-rest-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line item records store the related module and it's id, rather than attempting to link these via the relationship call you may have more luck setting the fields on the line item record.

I.e. Setting `'parent_type' => 'AOS_Invoices'` and `'parent_id' => 'TheInvoiceId'` when creating/updating the `aos_products_quotes` record.

Comment: Seems to be working fine now with the initial generation.